# Can't compile LiquidSoap 1.3 from Source

Tags: aac, liquidsoap

I'm trying to install LiquidSoap from source because I need AAC+ support (fdk-aac). I did tests with Ubuntu 18.04, Debian 9 and CentOS 7.5, all giving the same error.

After ./configure (that runs ok), when I run "make":

```
File "tools/rqueue.ml", line 1:
Error: Could not find the .cmi file for interface tools/rqueue.mli.
../Makefile.rules:192: recipe for target 'tools/rqueue.cmx' failed
make[3]: *** [tools/rqueue.cmx] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/liquidsoap/liquidsoap/src'
../Makefile.rules:67: recipe for target 'all-auto-ocaml-prog' failed
make[2]: *** [all-auto-ocaml-prog] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/liquidsoap/liquidsoap/src'
Makefile.rules:27: recipe for target 'all-subdirs' failed
make[1]: *** [all-subdirs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/liquidsoap/liquidsoap'
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm stuck here. I did everything possible, installed all libs (apt-get) and ocaml packages. I'm sure that nothing is missing. What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because of some issue with the build system.

Have you tried building via opam? This is the supported way to do it with liquidsoap. See here: http://www.liquidsoap.info/download.html

Otherwise, I'd suggest bringing the conversation to the github repositoryhere:https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap/issues/

Comment: No, the build system is ok, I did tests with 3 different distros. Using opam I get errors on different situations.